# Cover - art display for songs

Tags: quicktime

I am developing a music player for streaming online data and i need to display cover -art of songs being played. I need to know whether cover - art is a part of data stream or do players set a default image with songs being played.

Comment: I guess by "qt" you mean quicktime? If so, I'd retag the post as "quicktime", as "qt" is used here for the Qt GUI toolkit.

Comment: Yes by Qt i mean quicktime...